# How are stellar elemental abundances quoted?

Tags: the-sun, hydrogen, elemental-abundances, helium

Close to the bottom of page 4 of [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1005161325181#page-1) (marked as page 164 in the upper left corner) states

> Values are given in the logarithmic scale usually adopted by astronomers, A$_{e\ell}$ = log N$_{e\ell}$/N$_H$ + 12.0, where N$_{e\ell}$ is the abundance by number.

I have never used stellar elemental abundances in this way, so I want to check a few things.

First of all, **is the logarithm used by this paper log$_{10}$ or log$_e$ (often written ln)?**  My guess is log$_e$ because of what follows.

Let's say I want to calculate the elemental abundance of He relative to H.  I believe the correct math would be to do the following

$$\frac{\textrm{N}_{He}}{\textrm{N}_H} = \textrm{exp}(\textrm{A}_{He} - 12.0)$$

**Is this the correct way to calculate the relative abundances?**  This equation gives a value of 0.343 for the helium abundance relative to hydrogen, which seems to be the correct value for the sun (the sun is usually quotes as being about 70% H and about 25% He, which gives a relative abundance of 0.357).  This correct value is what leads me to believe that the log is log$_e$.

Comment: What does it mean the bottom? Does not this paper have page/equation numbering?

Comment: @Py-ser, no the equations are not numbered.  It's an inline equation to boot.

Comment: I guess the page are numbered yet. The paper is a bit tough, please give the page number.

Comment: @Py-ser I already did in my original post of the question. To quote myself, "Close to the bottom of page 4 of this article (marked as page 164 in the upper left corner)"

Comment: Ops, sorry my mistake. I think I have the sources for an answer in a while.

Comment: For abundances Log means Log_10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your first question.

[This source](http://www.iisc.ernet.in/currsci/apr102004/921.pdf) clearly state that `Values are given in the usual logarithmic (dex) scale`, for the same formula that you quoted (similar job).
It is a bit tricky as the article "explains" the values, but you have to pay attention to the exact definition.

I think it is better to work out with an example. Let's take the `He`.

Good enough, you can better read the paper from [here](http://astro.uni-tuebingen.de/~rauch/TMAP/grevessesauval2001.pdf).

From the table, we have $A_{el}=10.93$. This is *the **abundance** of He relative to H* (in logarithmic scale).
From this you find out that $\frac{N_{el}}{N_H}=0.08 = 8\%$.
Indeed the work confirms this value (see the last page).

What you quote as `about 25% He`, is what they call `abundances by mass of [...] Helium (Y)`, which means $Y = mass\ of\ Helium / mass\ of\ Hydrogen$, and this is indeed about $25\%$.

Comment: So, not natural logarithm.

Comment: That reference says (dex), and you can obtain 8% only by decimal logarithm.